# Cannot derive user name for bundle with any system user in AEM

Tags: java, aem, sling

With an AEM 6.1 environment, I am trying to avoid the deprecated method `getAdministrativeResourceResolver` for getting the resource resolver in a java class.

I created system users and used existing system users that fit the right criteria (rep:authorizableId, jcr:uuid, rep:principalName properties populated and jcr:primaryType property being rep:SystemUser)

I configured the `Apache Sling Service User Mapping Service` to have the service mapping `org...:modifyJCR=oauthservice` (or corresponding user I tried)

[Screenshot of configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9oPU.png)

The code accessing the getServiceResourceResolver method:

```
BundleContext context = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(this.getClass()).getBundleContext();
ServiceReference ref = context.getServiceReference(ResourceResolverFactory.class.getName());
resolverFactory = (ResourceResolverFactory) context.getService(ref);
Map<String, Object> param = new HashMap<String, Object>();
param.put(ResourceResolverFactory.SUBSERVICE, "modifyJCR");
resourceResolver = resolverFactory.getServiceResourceResolver(param);
```

However, I'm still getting this error from my code:
`Cannot derive user name for bundle org... [491] and sub service modifyJCR`

Has anyone else still run into this error after making/using system users along with configuring the Service User Mapping Service?

Does the system user have to be impersonated by the user invoking the code? The java class is invoked via ecma script called by a workflow and I am logged in as admin. I have tried adding the administrators group as impersonators for multiple users but received an error.

Comment: Have you provided appropriate permissions to System User?

Comment: Sandeep, this is not a duplicate of the other question because I tried the exact same solution provided which did not work. I also gave the appropriate permissions to the system user, to access the right folders. It is not even getting to the piece to update pages since it is still hitting the login error.

Comment: Well, ok. This is strange. Only different thing i see is u call through ECMA script, we had used through Java Workflow Process only.

Comment: @SandeepKumar Thank you for your suggestions. I have posted what a coworker (different department) found on what they faced. The version of the sling api in our environment is too low to do this workaround.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out the version of the org.apache.sling.api package was too old (2.2.4) to do the new way around the deprecated method. Since that cannot be upgraded yet until AEM 6.2 (we don't want conflicts for versions), I will need to use the deprecated method. A more recent version such as 2.9.0 should allow using the Apache Sling Service User Mapping Service. I found this information from a coworker in a different department, they tried similar setup locally with a newer version of 2.9.0 and it worked while the older version did not work for them. Hopefully this helps someone who is stuck after following the solution of creating/using system users and configuring the mapper service but still gets a login exception.

Comment: This should be selected as the answer for the question

Answer (score 1):

This will work with getServiceResourceResolver method as well without any modifications for sling api version. Just ensure the bundle path is registered correctly in Apache Mapping Service console. This should be matched with group id and artifact id that is mentioned in pom.xml